# How to disagree under the [Flag or disagree...] review dialog?

Tags: support, review, flags, 10k-tools

I am looking at a post that is flagged as "not an answer". I think that it is an answer - not a particularly good one, but it's a fair attempt at answering a so-so question.

However, when I click [Flag or disagree...] button, the normal "Flag" dialog comes up. There is no option there to say "this answer does not need moderator's attention". What should I do when I want to inform the system that I looked at a flagged item, and I disagree with the flag?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The option to disagree with a flag is labeled as "invalid flag" in the flag dialog.

[image]

Comment: I must admit I was tripped up by this as well, because it's classed under 'needs moderator attention', but if you're disagreeing with the flag, that means you think that it *doesn't* need moderator attention...

Comment: @Benjol: So it is... I can't remember what the dialog looks like for reviewers and 10k users anymore as I can no longer access it even when I go to [/tools](http://stackoverflow.com/tools), and I don't have 10k anywhere else where I'm not a mod.

Comment: Fixed that for you :)

Comment: @Benjol: Cool, a freehand Silly Putty!

Comment: It seems like THIS screenshot is no longer valid. And the current setting is that there is NO "invalid flag" option in any section of the moderator tools. And I have not found an explanation of when I am expected to see that disagree option (need more rep? how much?)