# "It has invalid flags" option missing in the 10K tools

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, 10k-tools, invalid-flags

Now this is embarrassing: I seem to be unable to find the way to disagree with a moderation flag.

Of course I had a look at the help section and meta - problem is: The solutions provided are outdated.

Previously the correct answer was: Click `Flag or disagree...`, then `needs moderator attention`, then `invalid flag`.

Currently there is no option `invalid flag` anymore? How to proceed?

The options I can see (with barely more than 10K rep) are:

- it is spam
- it is offensive, abusive, or hate speech
- it is not an answer
- other (needs <> moderator attention)
  (and this one opens a text box to describe further)

Duplicate, but at this time outdated questions and answers are:

- [How to disagree under the [Flag or disagree…] review dialog?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164761/how-to-disagree-under-the-flag-or-disagree-review-dialog)
- [Flag or disagree won't let me disagree [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95000/flag-or-disagree-wont-let-me-disagree)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: No idea where you saw it, but "needs moderator attention" is the problem. You don't need to click it, "it has invalid flags" is visible right after clicking "flag or disagree". [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Os9I0.png).

Comment: Though I don't have 10k anywhere, this post has an image of what it's meant to look like: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215063/flag-option-in-the-10k-tools-review-should-act-the-same-as-flag-or-disagree/215067#215067

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy no that's wrong. This **is not implemented yet**, it's just a suggestion and a user script.

Comment: I stated ALL the options available to me right after clicking the button "flag or disagree...". I didn't click anything else. So if there is one option missing, this is the bug or misbehavior I am experiencing.

Comment: @Sven What post exactly was it? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Please use `@` when you reply, otherwise we'll miss what you say.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I was using that post for the image at the top of the question, is it not that way currently?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy oh my, you linked to specific answer. Right, and it's even completed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I haven't said I don't want to add one. Just did.

Comment: Cheers, this appears to be a bug then. There is a recent change that validates the user's reputation before showing the "invalid flags" option, probably it got a type. (e.g. 10K is actually 1024*10 = 10240)

Comment: @Sven now with bit more rep, do you see that option?

Comment: I must assume that this issue is some weird thing on my client side. I was able to see the correct menu with the same browser on a different machine and with a different browser on the same machine.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, and I have just found a solution!

The problem comes when you disable sending the referer header.

I have post [Allow to flag as "invalid flag" without requiring referer header](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220027/allow-to-flag-as-invalid-flag-without-requiring-referer-header) in order to fix this bug.

Meanwhile, you can enable referer header. On Firefox, just go to `about:config` and set

```
network.http.sendRefererHeader = 2
```

Comment: That sounds promising. Will test once I am back on my machine, and then act accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is still there:

[image]

Do note the highly specific location of this option.  You only get it in the 10K moderator tools page, Flags tab.  Sounds to me like you are clicking the "flag" link under a plain post, available to anybody.

Comment: I have to disagree, see my screenshot.

Comment: Well, that indeed looks different from mine :)  Other than recommending pressing Ctrl+F5 to flush the browser cache, I'd gladly hand this one over to the SE programmers.