# Allow to flag as "invalid flag" without requiring referer header

Tags: bug, flags, 10k-tools, invalid-flags

If I disable sending the referer header on Firefox, using one of these

```
network.http.sendRefererHeader = 0
network.http.sendRefererHeader = 1
```

...then I can't flag a flaged post post as "invalid flag".

It works with

```
network.http.sendRefererHeader = 2
```

See ["It has invalid flags" option missing in the 10K tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217522/it-has-invalid-flags-option-missing-in-the-10k-tools) for further details about the problem.