# Separate the "disagree" option in flag review interface

Tags: feature-request, review, flags, user-interface, usability

> **As of April 22<sup>nd</sup> 2014, [the 10k flags queue is no more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue)** thus the below isn't relevant

---

As it stands now, the "disagree with a flag" option is, unintuitively, buried in the middle of a bunch of "agree"-like options.  This has confused at least a few other people:

- [10k+ users can see flags now, but can't unflag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94186/10k-users-can-see-flags-now-but-cant-unflag)
- [How to disagree under the [Flag or disagree...] review dialog?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164761/how-to-disagree-under-the-flag-or-disagree-review-dialog)
- [Flag or disagree won't let me disagree](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95000/flag-or-disagree-wont-let-me-disagree)
- and me, 5 minutes ago.

For the sake of UX, I would like to see the disagree option somehow separated from all the rest, and preferably use the same word to provide a better cue to the user.  A couple ideas on how:

1. Draw a little horizontal rule and group the "agree flags" on one side, and the "disagree flag" on the other
2. Convert the "disagree" option into a button on the pop-up (e.g. <kbd>Flag Answer</kbd> <kbd>Disagree</kbd>)
3. Convert the "disagree" option into a button alongside the button that makes the pop-up (e.g. <kbd>Flag...</kbd> <kbd>Disagree</kbd> instead of <kbd>Flag or disagree...</kbd>)

Plus, "I am flagging this answer because it has invalid flags" sounds borderline counterproductive/oxymoronic. I've heard some people say that "flags don't do anything in and of themselves", (which I'm not sure on—I've been told too many spam/offensive flags automatically deletes a post) is merely a behind-the-scenes quirk; that distinction is irrelevant to non-mods.

[image: Flag review popup with annotations]

Comment: Absolutely agree.  I probably click NAA about 25% of the time by accident while I'm trying to click Invalid Flags (I always correct it, but that's extra work!)

Comment: That said, aren't they someday rolling out a new flagging interface and mechanism?  Someday?

Answer (score 0):

I think option 1 (the `hr` and moving it to the bottom) is the right one.  Disagree is a choice equivalent to the others, so it shouldn't be an entirely different button - we're not trying to encourage people to disagree, which is what a button would do - but it should be separated from the other reasons so it's visually distinct and harder to accidentally choose a flagging reason when trying to disagree with flags.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree. It's very unintuitive. I think the first option is the best. The hard rule will make it clear that there is a separation between the two areas. Perhaps the text for the disagree section can be in a different color as well to make it stand out better.